# Add user to Sharepoint database

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I created a web part for Sharepoint 2013 which reads the email address from the user that is currently logged in. I'm deploying locally and the only user I have is the administrator which has also no email address yet.

- Where can I add an email address for the administrator?
- Where can I create a new user account?

Sorry for these basic questions but I'm pretty new to SP and I couldn't find any solution on the web yet.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your SharePoint instance (if it is on o365 or on-prem).

In case of o365 it is being managed by Azure AD (you can use the o365 admin center to [change the email property](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-a-user-name-and-email-address-in-Office-365-fb5ac074-e203-4e1f-9843-b9d1a3e03297)) and if this is on-prem instance you have to change user property inside your Windows Server Active Directory.

After you do that make sure you run the full sync on the user profile job.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be done in the Active Directory. Search for "Active Directory Users and Computers" on your machine.